# Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity

Tags: php, xml, parsing, syntax, domdocument

we are using an file to create image site map

i got this errors on image-sitemap.xml file

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: http://netyab.net/sitemap-image.xml
Line Number 2, Column 1:Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 24 in /home2/netyabne/domains/netyab.net/public_html/base/sitemap/image.php on line 25
^
```

and this one in our source

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 24 in /home2/netyabne/domains/netyab.net/public_html/base/sitemap/image.php on line 25

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 133 in /home2/netyabne/domains/netyab.net/public_html/base/sitemap/image.php on line 25
```

how can solve it ?

```
http://netyab.net/sitemap-image.xml
```

line 24 and 25 in image.php file

```
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($result ['content']);
```

Comment: Encode the `&`s to their entities.

Comment: Show us your XML, obviously there is some problem with it // If it is XML you should use `loadXML()` and not `loadHTML()`